# A different way to access an element of a 2dimensional array in c

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anybody explain me why the following part of code produces the result 21?
Here is the code:

```
int a[2][4]={3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24};
cout << 2[1[a]];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the dupe's answer, `2[1[a]]` is `*(2 + *(1+a))`. Then `*(1+a)` is `a[1]`, which is the second set of four elements. Applying the same logic to the outer part gives us the third element of that second set.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks :)